# What are the bytes between the strings in Mifare NFC?

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

When I'm reading a Mifare classic 4k card from block to block and convert the bytes to hexadecimal and then to UTF8/ASCII I get weird characters that probably control bytes and not actual text. 
Since I'm just converting the whole block directly to UTF, what should I instead do to utilize those bits in between? 
Below are the readings I get and to the left the expected translated value.
If you convert the hex yourself you'll see there are strange characters between the words.

```
c5 42 4e 49 44 00 07 4f 4f 4f 4f 4f 4f 00 4b 42    "Åbnid" "OOOOOO" "KB" 
44 44 44 20 44 44 44 44 44 00 82 4d 00 c9 31 39    "DDD DDDDD" "M" "19"                     
39 34 34 33 34 32 00 d0 4e 4f 39 36 36 36 35 31     "944342" "NO966651"
00000000000070f78800000000000000
30 32 32 20 20 41 53 00 d3 54 4f 54 41 4c 20 4b    "022" "AS" "Total k"
 4f 4e 54 52 4f 4f 4f 20 41 53 20 00 c9 30 32 38    "ONTROOO AS" "028" 
37 30 34 33 33 00 c9 32 30 32 31 30 32 31 31 00    "70433" "20210211" 
00000000000070f78800000000000000
```

How can I implement a method that takes in either a string of hex or array of bytes[] and only returns the words by comma seperation?

Comment: You already asked that question. If you have an edit to your question please use the "edit" link on the original question but refrain from asking the question a second time.

Answer (score 2):

You can read by address, probably, you only require to read by data address.
Data Address start from 0 to 63 for Mifare Classic card, 16 sectors with 4 blocks (=1024 bytes)). But Address 0 always store UID or Manufacturer ID. So, start reading from Address 1, Address 2...Address 63. Let me break down for you,

```
 Sector 0: Address 0        , Address 1, Address 2, Address 3
          UID/ManufacturerID, Data     , Data     ,Sector Trail (KeyA,AccessKey,KeyB)
 Sector 1: Address 4, Address 5, Address 6, Address 7
           Data     , Data     , Data     , Sector Trail
 ...
 Sector 63 ...
 So Sector Trail = 00000000000070f78800000000000000
 KeyA = 000000000000
 AccessKey = 70f78800
 KeyB = 000000000000
```

So every sector, you skip the last address if you don't set read and write protection.So Try this.And Change accordingly, this could be sufficient to read

```
// final data
String data="";
// read sector 1 and 2
for(int sector = 1; sector < 3, sector++){
    // auth sector
    auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sector, bytekey3);
    if(auth) {
        // read blocks from sector
        data += convertHexToString(readBlockData(sector)).trim();
    }
}

// read block 
private String readBlockData(int sector) {
            String blockvalues = "";


            // Read all blocks in sector
            for (int block = 0; (block < mfc.getBlockCountInSector(sector)); ++block) {

                // Get block number for sector + block
                int blockIndex = (mfc.sectorToBlock(sector) + block);

                try {

                    // Create a string of bits from block data and fix endianness
                    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness                    
                    if (block < 3) {
                        // Read block data from block index
                        byte[] data = mfc.readBlock(blockIndex);
                        if (!(sector == 0 && block == 0)) {
                            String temp = ByteArrayToHexString(data);
                            blockvalues += temp;
                            Log.i(TAG, "Block " + blockIndex + " : " + temp);
                            rawData += ("Block " + blockIndex + " : " + temp + "\n");
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred  " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
            return blockvalues.trim();
}

 public String convertHexToString(String hex) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2) {

            //grab the hex in pairs
            String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
            //convert hex to decimal
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
            //convert the decimal to character
            sb.append((char) decimal);

            temp.append(decimal);
        }
        System.out.println("Decimal : " + temp.toString());

        return sb.toString().trim();
}

 private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) {
        int i, j, in;
        String[] hex = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A",
                "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        String out = "";

        for (j = 0; j < inarray.length; ++j) {
            in = inarray[j] & 0xff;
            i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
            i = in & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
        }
        return out;
    }
```

last part will be string manipulation. so basically, replay all the double quote with space and use String[]yourdata = data.split("\s+"); and you will get your data. Some of the code I borrow from this [link](https://github.com/codes29/RFIDReader)

Comment: My readings are from sector 1-2 and block 4-8

Comment: Are you using android phone nfc reader?

Comment: No, ive made my own app as this NFC card requires a spesific readKey, if your question was if im using an android device to read, then yes.

Comment: can you show me the code that give current hexs.

Comment: Authenticate `  auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sector, bytekey3);`  Read: `data = mfc.readBlock(bIndex + block);` and for converting i use:     `public  String bytesToHex(byte[] hashInBytes) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : hashInBytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));  
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }` Is it possible to format code in comment?

Comment: apparently cant format in comment. so, what you really wanna get is this byte "c5 42 4e 49 44 00 07 4f 4f 4f 4f 4f 4f 00 4b 42 44 44 44 20 44 44 44 44 44 00 82 4d 00 c9 31 39 39 34 34 33 34 32 00 d0 4e 4f 39 36 36 36 35 31
00000000000070f78800000000000000 30 32 32 20 20 41 53 00 d3 54 4f 54 41 4c 20 4b 4f 4e 54 52 4f 4f 4f 20 41 53 20 00 c9 30 32 38 37 30 34 33 33 00 c9 32 30 32 31 30 32 31 31 00 00000000000070f78800000000000000" to this string "Åbnid" "OOOOOO" "KB" "DDD DDDDD" "M" "19"  "944342" "NO966651" "022" "AS" "Total k" "ONTROOO AS" "028" "70433" "20210211". is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, BUT, some of these words are split between 2 blocks, EG  " "Total k" and  "ONTROOO AS" should be "Total kONTROOO" but im sure those bytes in between words are telling about that, some kinds of start read, stop read commands, but i dont know really